# invoke button submit using webkitbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

how to invoke form button submit on WebKitWebBrowser using c# code behind?
i can find the control using

```
webKitBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value", "argeure");
```

but is ther any method to call like this?

```
webKitBrowser.Document.GetElementById("signIn").Invoke("click");
```

Comment: If this is for auto-signin, why not use the System.Web's ability to send a POST request, and persist the cookie in a cookiestore?

Comment: i have no idea about it can you give me a good reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-login-to-website-via-program

Comment: Hi Claus, it's good solution except loading page to webbrowser i'll try it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with javascript. ie write some js to the WebKitWebBrowser, which gets the form element and calls on `.submit()` on it.