# Implementing InvokeMember method in WebKit WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webkit, bots

I am making a bot (for genomic research purpose) which will visit the particular website and insert some inputs on webpage.

I am using Webkit.Net WebBrowser control and I cant see any way to click a button programmatically because there is no method like InvokeMember. Is there any way to implement a click on a button?

Note: 
I have searched this question on stackoverflow and found some technique but I think it cant be done here as 
[Link of searched solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548702/invoke-button-submit-using-webkitbrowser)
information is not passed through querystring etc in my case.

Comment: @Saad_Qureshi I think using java-script will be the easiest solution

Comment: It is an Open Source project, they are asking for devs to help out adding the many missing pieces.  Don't hesitate to help, that's how these things get done.  If it isn't your cup of tea then just don't use it, you'll have little trouble getting this done with the .NET WebBrowser class.