# How to avoid security page while doing automatic login using web browser control?

Tags: c#

Friends
My task is using C# window application have to automatic login to site and on that first page which comes after login. there is link and after clicking on that link user can download excel file.
i can implement this like i can make exe of this and put it on my schedule and i ll set the time. so it automatically download the excel file.

i completed till login code but am facing problem after login it shows me security question page.
so how can i avoid this page? And when exe executed through scheduling then it don't have show any front end? so i have to hide front end so that is also remaing.

Any suggestion related to my concept or code will be very helpful to me.

Comment: This may help if you have an account with the website? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of those security questions and captchas is to avoid exactly what you are trying to achieve and prevent access to the site from automated scripts and bots. If the authors of the website decided to put them on the website it is because they didn't want their website to be used the way you intent to use it. So I am afraid that there is no official and easy way to achieve this task.

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to understand what he was after in the OP. I read it, and couldn't understand the issue or what was being attempted.

Comment: The question was pretty clear to me. The OP is attempting to do screen scraping of a website.