# Authorization to web site from wpf/winforms app via https

Tags: c#, wpf, https, authorization

I'm trying to send a POST request to some site with my login and password. The site is using https for auhorization. Using Fiddler I can see my request from browser, the body of POST looks like `login%5Bts%5D=1370286692&login%5Bkey%5D=c8c55acb675801b7389968dfaf9a30eb&login%5BuseSSL%5D=0&source=%2F&login%5Bu%5D=MYLOGIN&login%5Bp%5D=MYPASS&Submit=`  . I can't understand how can I generate such request from my C# code. So is there any way to login to this site form my app?

Comment: @H.B. Maybe I searched badly, can you give a link please?

Comment: I probably could if i searched but won't, i just know that this is an extremely popular question and back when i searched for it i got my answers without asking. Try google with `site:stackoverflow.com` if the on-site search fails you.

Comment: Found answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program