# Need help,How can i use HttpWebRequest login www.shutterstock.com,Other website is fine

Tags: c#, web, authentication, httpwebrequest

I use my account to login www.shutterstock.com in IE or Firefox is fine,but use HttpWebRequest  cann't,I have save cookie data in CookieContainer(),My Programe Get cookie is different number with IE Browser,why not,I have assign the request info UserAgent,Referer,Host ...

Anyone can tell me what's problem.How Can i do can login this web.following is my code.
account is virtual,not true.

```
        string session_id = "";
        string str_key = "";
        string str_value = "";
        string url = "";
        url = "http://www.shutterstock.com/";

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.MediaType = "GET";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webRequest.Referer = "";
        webRequest.Host = "www.shutterstock.com";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        OutputCookieData(url, response);

        foreach (Cookie cookie_object in response.Cookies)
        {               
            str_key = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookie_object.Name);
            str_value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookie_object.Value);
            if (str_key == "ssssidd")
            {
                session_id = str_value;
                break;
            }
            //str_cookie += str_key + "=" + str_value + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        WriteDayLog(responseData);

        // extract the viewstate value and build out POST data          
        string postData =
              String.Format(
                 "user=susimage&pass=110205&session_id={0}",
                 session_id
              );
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        // have a cookie container ready to receive the forms auth cookie
        // now post to the login form
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.shutterstock.com/login.mhtml") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.Referer = "http://www.shutterstock.com/";
        webRequest.Host = "secure.shutterstock.com";


        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postData);
        requestWriter.Close();

        // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues

        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        OutputCookieData("https://secure.shutterstock.com/login.mhtml", response);
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        WriteDayLog(responseData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a [Web Browser Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx). It will automatically grab the cookie informatino from IE and pass that through.

Comment: good idea,but i nead read cookie and when download Image enter verify code.

Comment: if use webRequest, How can i do?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure that out

Comment: I have resolve it use this method,get response header set-cookie then request set the cookie back to the request header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program